# Image sent as HTTP POST gets corrupted while writing to file in server

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post, http-post

I use the below code to post an image to my server.

```
NSString *localCacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Downloads"];
NSString *localPathToSaveFile = [localCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lion.jpg"]];

NSMutableString *urlForUploadingAttachment = MY_SERVER_URL;

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localPathToSaveFile];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"--------";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localPathToSaveFile], 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", @"lion.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlForUploadingAttachment]];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString* returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

And in the server side .net application I write the file as

```
    public void SaveAttachment(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }
        string fullFilePath = filepath + "\\" + fileName;
        using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(fullFilePath))
        {
            CopyStream(Request.InputStream, file);
            try
            {
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }

    public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024]; int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

But the file which is written by the server is corrupted. Even though the file gets written, I cannot open it or preview it. The file size is also as expected. But when I double click the image I get the message that the file is either damaged, corrupted or too large. What is the issue here? Can some one please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For image posting by `POST Method` , here simple code use it as per your requirement:

```
NSString  *imgPath = fullPathOfYourImage;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imgPath])
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                                                        
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"YourImageName.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                                                                                               ^..YourImageName….^

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```

Comment: There is no error, the server reads the Request.InputStream and writes it to the file without any error. But the file that is written is corrupt or damaged. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: try with other files as the code snippet given by @iPatel is all correct. Also do check the imageData, if its ok or not.

Comment: I tried pdf files, they have no issue. They are correctly saved in the server. I encounter this only for image files. :(